# Cannot hide a button in C# by detecting if a GridView is empty after the GridView has been filtered

Tags: c#, gridview, hide

So before I continue you should know I've tried GridView1.Rows.Count == 0, SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Count==0, and I've looked all over but can't seem to find an answer. Here is my code:

```
 protected void FilterLP_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ddl = FilterDDL.SelectedValue;
        if (ddl == "Maintenance_ID")
        {
            RegularExpressionValidator1.Enabled = true;
            RegularExpressionValidator1.ValidationExpression = "^[0-9]*$";
            string FilterExpression = "Convert(Maintenance_ID , 'System.String')  LIKE '%{0}%'";
            SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Clear();
            SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add(new ControlParameter(FilterDDL.SelectedValue, "TextBox1", "Text"));
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = FilterExpression;
        }
        else
        {
            string FilterExpression = string.Concat(FilterDDL.SelectedValue, " LIKE '%{0}%'");
            SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Clear();
            SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add(new ControlParameter(FilterDDL.SelectedValue, "TextBox1", "Text"));
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = FilterExpression;
        }
        if (GridView1.Visible == false)
        {
            AddRecord_Btn.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Now where I have `GridView1.Visible == false` is pretty much just a placeholder but after doing a stack trace I found that there are hidden rows even after I've done Rows.Count or any count.

Here is GridView in the design:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" DataKeyNames="Laptop_ID" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
    <Columns>
     ...
```

So I have a message that comes up when there are no records after the filter.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: [Update panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094722/how-to-hide-and-display-aspbuttons-in-asp-net-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to manually rebind the GridView after your custom filter logic.